# An object is not getting updated when sending by ref (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, queue

I'm trying to make a program for a queue of customers (FIFO),
I've already made both of the classes, but when I send an object by ref and I try to deposit him account, its getting updated only inside th function, but when it gets back to main, I can't see it updated and it stays on 0.
The issue is that when I enter deposit with c3, its adding 333 to the account, but when I try to print q1, it prints 0.

My code:

**Customer.cpp**

```
Customer::Customer(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->customerNum = accountId;
    this->next = NULL;
    this->accountBalance = 0;
    accountId++;
}

// Copy c'tor
Customer::Customer(const Customer& x) : 
    accountBalance(x.accountBalance), customerNum(x.customerNum), name(x.name) {
        this->next = NULL;
}
void Customer::deposit(int amountToDeposit) {
    this->accountBalance += amountToDeposit;
    cout << "Added " << amountToDeposit << " to your account." << endl;
    cout << "The new balance is: " << this->accountBalance << endl;
}
```

**Queue.cpp**

```
// copy c'tor
Queue::Queue(Queue& x) {
    this->first = x.first;
    this->rear = x.rear;
}


void Queue::print() {
    Queue* temp = new Queue(*this);
    if (temp->first == NULL) {
        cout << "The queue is empty!" << endl;
    }
    else if (temp->first != NULL && temp->rear == NULL) {
        temp->first->printAccount();
    }
    else {
        while (temp->first != NULL) {
            temp->first->printAccount();
            temp->first = temp->first->getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Customer.h"
#include "Queue.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {

    Queue q1;
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << "Is q1 empty ? " << q1.isEmpty() << endl;
    Customer c1 = Customer("Number One");
    Customer c2 = (string) "Number Two";
    Customer *c3 = new Customer("Number Three");
    q1.enqueue(c1);
    cout << "Is q1 empty ? " << q1.isEmpty() << endl;
    q1.enqueue(c2);
    q1.enqueue(*c3);
    q1.print();
    cout << endl;

    c1.deposit(111);
    c2.deposit(222);
    c3->deposit(333); **This is the line which is not getting updated.(I can't change the main, I need another solution)**
    q1.print(); ** prints 0 in account balance for c3**
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Queue has 2 pointer for rear and first(front), and it saves the customers in the queue one by one, then when I want to print the queue it will print the front of the queue and then go to the next of this node and him the front.

Comment: *and everything works great, but when I send an object by ref* -- which means everything is *not* working great.  Also, all of your user-defined copy constructors are bogus.  They do only shallow copies when they should be doing deep copies.

Comment: Please only post the relevant code and not your complete project

Comment: `#define __Customer_H` `#define __Queue_H` those identifiers are reserved. By defining them, your program will have undefined behaviour. You should use another header guard.

Comment: I believe it is because you pass the object to queue not the pointer

Comment: I've updated the post, @PaulMcKenzie if you can help me fix the copy c'tors I'd thanks you, I'm new to C++.

Comment: If you look inside `enqueue`, you will see that you're copying the argument in the general case.

Comment: please post a [mre], what does `enqueue` do?

Comment: A user-defined copy constructor is supposed to construct an independent copy of the object you are passing in.  You should not be sharing memory addresses (as your original code was doing, and now is still wrong with `this->next = NULL;`).  That means you are supposed to have allocated brand new memory for the copy, not share pointer addresses.  That is what is called a "deep copy".  If you don't understand, I suggest either using objects (not pointers), or if using pointers, read up on how to properly construct/assign copies of objects that contain pointers to dynamically allocated memory.